Pull image from artifact registry from a gce instance
I'm new to GCP and i can't find any good resource on internet.
I just deployed a GCE VM (Ubuntu 22.04) and i've installed Docker engine on it.
Docker is working.
On my local machine I've pushed an image to GCR correctly with :latest tag.
On the console i can see: europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev///
If i try to pull the image (even after gcloud auth print-access-token | docker login -u oauth2accesstoken --password-stdin https://europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev) i get
 ✘ api Error      Head "https://europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev/v2/<my-project>/<repository>/<image-name>/manifests/latest": denied: Unauthenticated request. ...            0.3s
I understood that i have to give access from the instance (Service account) to the GCR:

What else i need to do?

IIRC the default Compute Engine Service Account has access to Artifact Registry and so you should not need to adjust the IAM policy. Another way to authenticate is to use the Metadata Service to get a token. See my answer and replace HOST="https://europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev".

came up with a silly solution. gcloud auth print-access-token | docker login -u oauth2accesstoken --password-stdin https://europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev was run NOT under sudo, while docker pull was
